# Building sub-dict from large dict using recursion

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that links various species in a parent-daughter decay chain. For example:

```
d = {
    'A':{'daughter':['B']},
    'B':{'daughter':['C']},
    'C':{'daughter':['D']},
    'D':{'daughter':['None']},
    'E':{'daughter':['F']},
    'F':{'daughter':['G']},
    'G':{'daughter':['H']},
    'H':{'daughter':[None]}
}
```

In this dictionary, the top level key is the 'parent' and the 'daughter' (i.e. what the parent decays to in the chain) is defined as a key:value item in the dictionary attached to the parent key. When `None` is given for the daughter, that is considered to be the end of the chain.

I want a function to return a sub dictionary containing the items in the chain according to the users input for the starting parent. I would also like to know the position of each item in the chain. In the sub-dictionary this can be a second field (`'position'`).

For example, if the user wants to start the chain at 'A', I would like the function to return:

```
{'A':{'position':1, 'daughter':['B']},
 'B':{'position':2, 'daughter':['C']},
 'C':{'position':3, 'daughter':['D']},
 'D':{'position':4, 'daughter':['None']}}
```

Similarly, if the starting value was 'E' I would like it to return:

```
{'F':{'position':1, 'daughter':['G']},
 'G':{'position':3, 'daughter':['H']},
 'H':{'position':4, 'daughter':['None']}}
```

This is relatively easy when the linking is one-to-one i.e. one item decays into another, into another etc.

If I now use a more complex example, as below, you can see that 'B' actually decays into both 'C' and 'D' and from there onwards the chains are separate.

A => B => C => E => G   and   A => B => D => F => H

```
d = {
    'A':{'daughter':['B']},
    'B':{'daughter':['C', 'D']},
    'C':{'daughter':['E']},
    'D':{'daughter':['F']},
    'E':{'daughter':['G']},
    'F':{'daughter':['H']},
    'G':{'daughter':[None]},
    'H':{'daughter':[None]}
}
```

In this case I would like a function to return the following output. You'll notice because of the diversion of the two chains, the position values are close to the level in the heirachy e.g. C=3 and D = 4, but not exactly the same. I don't want to follow the C chain all the way down, and then repeat for the D chain.

```
{'A':{'position':1, 'daughter':['B']},
 'B':{'position':2, 'daughter':['C']},
 'C':{'position':3, 'daughter':['E']},
 'D':{'position':4, 'daughter':['F']}
 'E':{'position':5, 'daughter':['G']}
 'F':{'position':6, 'daughter':['H']}
 'G':{'position':8, 'daughter':['None']}
 'H':{'position':9, 'daughter':['None']}
}
```

Any thoughts? The function should be able to cope with more than one diversion in the chain.

Mark

Comment: Google for depth first search

Comment: I didn't think I was defining anything with the name 'list'?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go all the way down from C, then [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) may help。

```
def bfs(d, start):
    answer = {}
    queue = [start]
    head = 0

    while head < len(queue):
        # Fetch the first element from queue
        now = queue[head]
        answer[now] = {
            'position': head+1,
            'daughter': d[now]['daughter']
        }

        # Add daughters to the queue
        for nxt in d[now]['daughter']:
            if nxt == None:
                continue
            queue.append(nxt)

        head += 1

    return answer

d = {
    'A': {'daughter': ['B']},
    'B': {'daughter': ['C', 'D']},
    'C': {'daughter': ['E']},
    'D': {'daughter': ['F']},
    'E': {'daughter': ['G']},
    'F': {'daughter': ['H']},
    'G': {'daughter': [None]},
    'H': {'daughter': [None]}
}

print(bfs(d, 'A'))
```